# How to check if AWS instance is really available

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm starting new AWS instance (with Windows) from code:

```
RunInstancesResponse launchResponse = ec2Client.RunInstances(launchRequest);
```

Then I'm requesting it's state:

```
   var instanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
   var response = ec2Client.DescribeInstances(instanceRequest);
```

And when state is 16/Running I'm trying to connect to this instance, but it fails. Later it is possible to connect.
In the AWS console I see 'Status Checks' that start running when image get status 'Running' and I think when 'Status Checks' are completed image become really available.

Comment: I think from Amazon's point of view the instance is running. The problem is that the operating system on the instance hasn't finished booting/starting-up yet and may not be ready to accept connections. You may have to just wait another minute or two after AWS says the instance is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the running state, I agree with Mark B.  The running state doesn't guarantee that the OS has finished starting up, that user data has finished running, that your generated password is available, etc. Checking status may *coincidentally* work better for you because -- by default -- it only checks running instances, but the benefit may only be coincidental because these checks likewise don't check many of the internal operations on your instance that you may be interested in.

To look at [status checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html), you'll want to use a different API:

**DescribeInstanceStatus:**

- Request: [DescribeInstanceStatusRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2DescribeInstanceStatusRequest.html)
- Response: [DescribeInstanceStatusResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2DescribeInstanceStatusResponse.html)

  - InstanceStatus Object: [InstanceStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2InstanceStatus.html)

**Simple Example:**

```
using (IAmazonEC2 client = new AmazonEC2Client())
{
    string instanceId = "i-abcd1234";

    DescribeInstanceStatusResponse response = client.DescribeInstanceStatus(
        new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest
        {
            InstanceIds = new List<string> { instanceId }
        });

    InstanceStatus status = response?.InstanceStatuses.FirstOrDefault(
        x => x.InstanceId == instanceId
    );

    if (status != null)
    {
        // Perform your checks on InstanceStatus here
    }
}
```

Some other alternative ideas:

- Look at publishing a message from the instance [user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)
- Poll an endpoint on the instance until it becomes available. If this instance is specifically hosting web services, this is a better approach and can be automated with [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Anthony - don't rely on status from the API. 
You said:

> "I'm trying to connect to this instance, but it fails. Later it is
>   possible to connect"

Why not do that in your code?

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        // try and connect to whatever you're waiting for on your instance(s)
        ConnectToInstance("instance IP address goes here");
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still waiting to connect: " + e)        
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Probably add a maximum time to wait. Then you're not relying on AWS status or userdata or windows service start up delays etc.